# What sort of ring-theoretic properties does the representation ring of a compact Lie group possess?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Recall the definition of the [representation ring](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/representation+ring) $R(G)$ of a compact Lie group $G$. I'd like a reference that gives me basic ring-theoretic properties that $R(G)$ always has, or enough info that I can check for various properties myself.

Comment: What about structure? $R(G)$ is always a $\lambda$-ring, although it has even more structure than this, e.g. it's acted on by all Schur functors.

Comment: I'm thinking things like Noetherian, Henselian, finite (whatever) dimension, etc. The sorts of things that come up in vanilla commutative algebra.

Comment: As the answer you've accepted indicates, $R(G)$ is pretty boring as a ring; I think the proper point of view on it is as a ring-with-basis. (And then it's very interesting.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assume that $G$ is connected. Let $T$ be a maximal torus of $G$. Restriction induces a map $R(G) \to R(T)$. Note that $R(T)$ is a Laurent polynomial ring in $r$ variables where $r$ is the rank. Because the conjugates of $T$ fill up $G$, Peter-Weyl implies that this map is injective. Moreover, if $W$ is the Weyl group, then the image of this map lies in $R(T)^W$, and I think this map is always an isomorphism. So $R(G)$ is about as nice as possible: in particular, it is a finitely generated integral domain, so Noetherian of finite Krull dimension, etc. A lot is known about invariants of Weyl groups so you can probably get even more explicit information than this.

*Example.* Let $G = \text{U}(n)$. Then $R(T)$ is a Laurent polynomial ring in $n$ variables, the Weyl group is $W \cong S_n$ acting by permutation, and the invariant subring is $\mathbb{Z}[e_1, ..., e_n, e_n^{-1}]$ where $e_i$ is the $i^{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomial, which corresponds to $\Lambda^i(\mathbb{C}^n)$.

Comment: Note that a good reference for the structure of representation rings is section VI.2 of Springer GTM 98 *Representations of Compact Lie Groups* by Brocker and tom Dieck.   In particular, the ring is finitely generated (hence noetherian) and has more precise properties if $G$ is simply connected, etc.

Comment: @Jim: thanks for the reference! My claim above is Proposition 2.1 in that section, and the more precise information when $G$ is simply connected is Corollary 2.11. In this case $R(G)$ is actually the polynomial ring on $r$ variables where $r$ is the rank.

Comment: In fact, I just found that Segal proved $R(G)$ is finitely generated for any compact $G$, by using finite generation over $R(U(n))$.

Comment: @David: I should have added an online link to Segal's 1968 paper: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=PMIHES_1968__34__113_0 (which Serre discusses in the finite group case, in his textbook on finite group representations).